# FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android

/* I havent made any changes in he code..previously it was running properly.I donno why it showing runtime exception when executed. Please help */

```
                        package com.example.klarity;

                        import java.io.BufferedReader;
                        import java.io.IOException;
                        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
                        import java.net.MalformedURLException;
                        import java.net.URL;
                        import java.util.ArrayList;

                            import org.json.JSONArray;
                            import org.json.JSONException;
                            import org.json.JSONObject;

                            import android.os.AsyncTask;
                            import android.os.Bundle;
                            import android.os.StrictMode;
                            import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
                            import android.view.Menu;
                            import android.view.MenuItem;
                            import android.view.View;
                            import android.widget.AdapterView;
                            import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
                            import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
                            import android.widget.Spinner;
                            import android.widget.Toast;

                public abstract class Screen1 extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

                    Spinner practiceSpin; 
                    Spinner projectSpin;
                    JSONObject projDet;
                    JSONArray projArr;
                    ArrayList<String> arrData=new ArrayList<String>();
                    ArrayList<String> arrPrac=new ArrayList<String>();
                    int[] project;
                    URL url;
                    BufferedReader br;
                    String selected1;




                    /*sprivate final static String JSON_DATA =
                            "{" 
                                    + "  \"practice\": [" 
                                    + "    {"                 
                                    + "      \"name\": \"autosar\""                   
                                    + "    }," 
                                    + "    {" 
                                    + "      \"name\": \"powertrain\"" 
                                    + "    },"                                                  //JSONArray for PRACTICES created
                                    + "    {" 
                                    + "      \"name\": \"JSONArray-2\""
                                    + "    },"
                                    + "    {" 
                                    + "      \"name\": \"JSON-3\""
                                    + "    }"
                                    + "  ]" 
                                    + "}"; */


                    private final static String JSON_DATA2 =
                            "{" 
                                    + "  \"project\": [" 
                                    + "    {"                 
                                    + "      \"name\": \"Project-1\""                   
                                    + "    }," 
                                    + "    {" 
                                    + "      \"name\": \"Project-2\"" 
                                    + "    },"                                                  //JSONArray for PROJECTS created
                                    + "    {" 
                                    + "      \"name\": \"Project-3\""
                                    + "    },"
                                    + "    {" 
                                    + "      \"name\": \"Project-4\""
                                    + "    }"
                                    + "  ]" 
                                    + "}"; 


                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen1);

                        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); 
                        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                        ConnectionHelper con = new ConnectionHelper();
                        String response = con.doInBackground(); //readUrl will be copied in response.
                        String tokens[] = response.split("\\*");


                    /*  //PRACTICE ARRAY CODE 
                        try {
                            projDet=new JSONObject(JSON_DATA);
                            projArr=projDet.getJSONArray("practice");


                            for(int n = 0; n < projArr.length(); n++)
                            {
                                JSONObject projDet = projArr.getJSONObject(n);
                                arrPrac.add(projArr.getJSONObject(n).getString("name"));
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                            System.out.println("exception occured");
                        } */

                        try {

                            practiceSpin=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerPractice);
                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_proj1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,tokens);     //"The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity, int, int, JSONArray) 

                            adapter_proj1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            practiceSpin.setAdapter(adapter_proj1); 
                            practiceSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
                            System.out.println("exception occured in 2nd catch");
                        }


                        /* //PROJECT ARRAY CODE
                        try {
                            projDet=new JSONObject(JSON_DATA2);
                            projArr=projDet.getJSONArray("project");


                            for(int n = 0; n < projArr.length(); n++)
                            {
                                JSONObject projDet = projArr.getJSONObject(n);
                                arrData.add(projArr.getJSONObject(n).getString("name"));
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                            System.out.println("exception occured");
                        }


                        try {
                            //PROJECT ARRAY ADAPTER
                            projectSpin=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerProject);
                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_proj = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,arrData);     //"The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity, int, int, JSONArray) 
                            adapter_proj.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            projectSpin.setAdapter(adapter_proj); 


                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
                            System.out.println("exception occured in 2nd catch");
                        } */

                    }

                    public void onItemSelected(android.widget.AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                         String selected1 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                     }; 





                    @Override
                    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.screen1, menu);
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                        int id = item.getItemId();
                        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                    }

                    private class ConnectionHelper extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
                        @Override
                        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                            try {
                                url = new URL("http://192.168.1.34/aditya/getAllPractices.php");
                            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            try {
                                br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            String readUrl = "";
                            try {
                                readUrl=br.readLine();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return readUrl;
                        }
                    }
```

}

This is what logCat is showing :

```
                02-19 19:15:40.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1487): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                02-19 19:15:40.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1487): Process: com.example.klarity, PID: 1487
                02-19 19:15:40.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1487): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.klarity/com.example.klarity.Screen1}: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.example.klarity.Screen1 cannot be instantiated
                02-19 19:15:40.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
                02-19 19:15:40.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                02-19 19:15:40.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                02-19 19:15:40.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                02-19 19:15:40.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                02-19 19:15:40.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                02-19 19:15:40.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                02-19 19:15:40.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                02-19 19:15:40.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                02-19 19:15:40.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                02-19 19:15:40.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                02-19 19:15:40.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1487): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.example.klarity.Screen1 cannot be instantiated
                02-19 19:15:40.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1553)
                02-19 19:15:40.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
                02-19 19:15:40.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
                02-19 19:15:40.467: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     ... 10 more
```

/* This is the problem occuring sudenly..No changes are made to code. I was running soothly  before.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use an abstract class itself as an activity, you must either have a concrete implementation (which extends this abstract one) or remove the abstract keyword.